# dropdown will accept a value that is not part of the list as well in Knockout

Tags: select, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

When entering an E-mail address, the user will have to select the E-mail 
 domain from the pre-defined list (e.g., gmail.com; outlook.com; hotmail.com).

The Domain dropdown will accept a value that is not part of the list as well.

I should have both select and input feature.

HTML:

```
 <!-- Mulitple array of emails   -->
    <div>
       <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tbody data-bind='foreach: billDeliveryEmails'>
             <tr>
                <td><input class='required' data-bind='value: userName' /></td>
                <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableEmailDomains(), value: domainName, optionsText: 'domainName', optionsValue: 'domainName'"></select></td>
                <td><a  data-bind="click:'removeDeliveryEmailAddress'">Delete</a></td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
       <a class="atm-bloque-link" data-bind="click:'addDeliveryEmailAddress'">Agregue otra direccion de email</a>
    </div>
```

VM:

// Domain class

```
 function Domain(domainName) {
            var self = this;
            self.domainName = domainName;
           }

    billDeliveryEmails : [],
availableEmailDomains : ko.observableArray([
        new Domain("hotmail.com"),
        new Domain("yahoo.com")
    ])


     addDeliveryEmailAddress: function ($element, data, context, bindingContext, event) {

            bindingContext.$root.billDeliveryEmails.push({
                userName: "",
                domainName: this.viewModel.get('availableEmailDomains')[0]
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        },

        removeDeliveryEmailAddress: function ($element, data, context, bindingContext, event) {

            bindingContext.$root.billDeliveryEmails.splice(0, 1)
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Comment: if someone has downvoted, can he tell the reason. cause it is the requirement i came across and could not find solution on google.

Comment: What have you got so far? Are you familiar with how [observableArrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) work?

Comment: Which input is the one that should add to the available email list? Looks like you have an input that adds to 'billDeliveryEmails', but not one that adds to 'availableEmailDomains'. Pushing items into the 'availableEmailDomains' observableArray should update the select list UI automatically.

Comment: They say availableEmailDomains should be both select from options and input value manually

Comment: Your code above is missing an input to add email domains

Comment: like this but in knockoutJS  [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link in your comment, here's an example:

```js
function Domain(domainName) {
  var self = this;
  self.domainName = domainName;
}
           
var vm = function () {
 var self = this;
 self.browser = ko.observable();
  self.browserList = ko.observableArray([
   new Domain('yahoo.com'),
    new Domain('hotmail.com')
  ])
}();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" data-bind="value: browser" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers" data-bind="foreach: browserList">
  <option data-bind="text: domainName">
</datalist>

<br />
Your browser is: <span data-bind="text: browser"></span>
```

An observable array is used to populate the list and a regular observable tracks the selected value.